# MySQL Query with UNIX_TIMESTAMP Not Working

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to see if a field (`end_date`) in a MySQL database in the form of **2015-6-11 21:28:02** is greater than the current time.  Essentially, is that field in the future or not.

Here is my PHP Code:

```
$current_time = time();
$sql = "SELECT member_id, course_id, FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."vbc_status WHERE end_date < NOW()";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $db);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $echo $row['member_id'];
}
```

I keep getting an error:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /path/to/script.php on line 373.

Line 373 is the `while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {` part.

Any ideas of how this should be fixed?

Comment: What exactly is the error message you get?

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /path/to/my/script.php on line 373

Comment: Ugh. You're using `mysql_query`, aren't you? You're calling that function incorrectly, wrong arguments, the query string itself is probably fine. Keep in mind a modern database driver like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices.

Comment: if you have a moment please read [My Post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/2733506) about how to ask sql questions... it has a lot of good tips and tricks to help you ask a question.

Comment: Updating things to PDO is on my to-do list later on.  Right now, I'm just trying to keep things consistent.

Comment: Since your code is busted and not working, might as well do it correctly in PDO. It takes *literally* two lines to covert code like this.

Answer (score 3):

Why not skip all that and just do this:

```
WHERE end_date < NOW()
```

Converting with `UNIXTIME` is extremely abusive on your database, it needs to evaluate that for every row in the table and cannot use indexes. The date field itself will evaluate very quickly if indexed.

Comment: Changed it to `$sql = "SELECT member_id, course_id, FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."vbc_status WHERE end_date < NOW()";` and I'm still getting the error.

Comment: Yes, because you're not calling the query function correctly. Read the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) documentation to see how you're supposed to call it, as it requires a valid connection handle unless one has been established previously, and note the **big red box**.

Comment: looks like you have an issue with how you are executing your query.. also echo $sql after you create it

Comment: So, `SELECT member_id, course_id FROM `AT_vbc_status` WHERE end_date > NOW()` works fine when I use this directly in PHP MyAdmin.  However, this same logic isn't working when I put it in PHP.  I'm also using similar logic later on in the code and it works fine.  I'm going to update my original post with more code.

Comment: There's something awry in how you're calling that query, so that would help. Add your connection call with the passwords redacted, if applicable.

Comment: I've updated my post.  Thanks and please check it out.

Comment: @gtilflm you need to supply the connection

Comment: @gtilflm Looks like your query failed, but as you're doing zero error checking you don't know what the problem is. The reason I **strongly** recommend PDO is it [supports exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) meaning errors are impossible to ignore.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set your variable format to same format used in the database.

```
define('DATETIME_SQL', 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
$current_time = date(DATETIME_SQL);
$sql = "SELECT member_id, course_id, FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."vbc_status WHERE end_date < $current_time";
```

Answer (score 0):

FOUND IT!!!

In `$sql = "SELECT member_id, course_id, FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."vbc_status WHERE end_date < NOW()";`  there is an unnecessary `,` after `course_id`.

Stupid syntax.... :)